# Git : Check whether a new version exist for the modified files in local repository

Tags: git

In the repository if let's say there is

- apple.c
- orange.c
- grape.c

If the `apple.c` and `orange.c` are modified in the local copy. Is there a git command to check the repo status for only these locally modified files (probably useful before checkin).

Comment: What do you mean by "check the *repo status*" (emphasis mine)? Remember also that your repository is exactly that—*yours*—so it changes only when *you* tell it to change, which is why I am so confused by what you mean by "repo status".

Answer (score 2):

I believe the OP is asking for a way to see if the files that have been changed locally have been updated on remote.

Here is what you can do:

Update remote repository's local cache via `git fetch`. Then, it should be possible to local uncommitted changes against the remote tracking branch. Try the following:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git diff origin/master
```

Note that `origin/master` is one local branch, a shorthand for `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which is the full name of the remote-tracking branch.

Comment: The idea is exactly what I meant but I am on a specific git branch. Also the git diff origin/master gives error

Comment: Try `git diff remotes/origin/master` ? This should work on _any_ local branch.

Comment: Sorry It worked... But with a small exception. My branch name is xyz and when doing git fetch origin/xyz it gives error. But it allows git fetch origin/master which takes my local repo to X commits behind. But I am able to do git diff origin/xyz. Now the only issue is to fetch the latest version from repo.

Comment: Got a perfect combo now..... A git pull and a git diff origin/xyz does what is required....

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
git diff apple.с
git diff orange.с
```

See [documentation](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-diff.html)

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` will show all changes in current directory.

`git diff <path to file>` will show changes for the file supplied

Similarly you can you can use `git add` like above to be more selective of which files you commit.